# Problems with objectAtIndex of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am developing a game for iPhone in which I have 2 arrays.

One with the objects "living" in the game, and when these objects "die" they are placed in another array to be removed from the first one in the end of the first loop.

This is necessary because if the object dies in the loop and it is removed immediately from the first array, the index is lost and sometimes gives an invalid address access.

Then I have an NSMutableArray that contains objects to be removed from the living objects array.

In the array with objects to remove, I am constantly adding and removing items. Sometimes when I use objectAtIndex with the array with items to remove, it is retuning me other object.

For example in the first moment `_enemiesToRemove` has 2 objects:

```
([0]-> 0x0a8b5120, [1]->0x18f3a090)

for(int i = [_enemiesToRemove count] - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    fish = [_enemiesToRemove objectAtIndex:i];
    [self removeEnemy:fish];
}
```

and then

```
int i = [_enemiesToRemove count] - 1
```

gives i=1 but when it is doing

```
[_enemiesToRemove objectAtIndex:i]
```

it is returning me other object with address 0xbfffcd58 and it should be [1]->0x18f3a090

What is happening here, somebody knows? It is not happening always. It happens randomly.

Comment: Are you perhaps iterating over the _enemiesToRemove array while adding/removing items from it?  If you are, then your index into the array will not necessarily be valid anymore...

Comment: What happens when you call [self removeEnemy:fish]?  Does it update the _enemiestoRemove array?